# Same website - Two pages competing for same keyword

Tags: seo, google-search

Trying to improving my website's ranks on google for a specific keyword (e.g. Samsung S6), I'm thinking about doing some experiments.
I've a wordpress based blog. Now, I've the category "Samsung S6" (url: example.com/samsung-s6), with only the latest 6 news + pagination. This ranks good, but it's a bit ugly as a landing page and I want a better rank.

I'm thinking about creating a new page Samsung S6 (url: example.com/samsungs6). This page will contain a product overlay (e.g. RAM, HD, screen size etc.), + product description + some images/youtube videos + latest 3 news + some links to other relevant pages in my website for that product, including a link to the category page.

What will happen in terms of SEO? Any idea if the new page could rank better than the category page, considering that it has more static elements? Not sure if google could detects duplicates, or two page comepting for the same keyword on the same website is a bad thing. Which are your ideas?

Comment: Creating pages focused on keywords is an SEO strategy from 6 years ago.  It doesn't work well today.   Now I would recommend being comprehensive on the subject.    Write several articles about it.   Answer questions about it and post the answers.  List places to buy it.  Make it so people say "Why would I go to any other website for it.   This site has everything."

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Actually, I've done everything you said. The website is quite good, what I'm looking for is "going from 80% good to 99% good", and the thing that needs a big improvent is this landing page :)

Answer (score 1):

You might be better off combining both into one page. You already have a page that's "a bit ugly as a landing page"; so improve that first. You want to add product overlay/description/images; so add those here.

UI is a bigger question, but my initial thought when reading your question was something like this:

[image: product page]

This means you end up with one strong, content-rich, visually-appealing page. Your SEO benefits from having a more clear landing page and users benefit from finding everything they want in one place.

Comment: Problem for this approach is: I'm using wordpress, with a third party theme. Customizing the category template could be a huge time-spending with every update of the theme. Is this solution worth the pain, or (considering this) could be a better solution to create the new page, which is also easily customizable?

If I didn't had this problem, I would have chosen this solution for sure :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a need to make the FIRST page you made about the given topic LINK naturally to the SECOND page and ... THIRD. The trick is to AVOID any indication that you are linking to a new page only for ranking. As soon as Google feels that there is a "need" on your part and not a logical expansion of quality, original content you STOP being an "authority" on the niche topic - in your case Samsung phones and you will not rank better.

So: Make a few new pages without any focus on the URL and a lot of focus on the CONTENT of the page. Then crown in all with a "conclusion page" that has the URL you wish and the same words in the Title meta.

Make sure to have your sitemap crawled at each stage.

Lastly: DO NOT EXPECT to last long in the top 10 for high volume searches as they are TIME-RELATED. You will need to get good inbound links to your pages to last long.

- Example: If you type on google.com "new web domains" you will find me in the first 3 since 1 year in organic results.